# Entity Framework Many To Many CRUD

Tags: entity-framework

I am playing around with Entity Framework for a POC project. 
In my database I have

`Category<-------CategoryProduct ------->Product`

(Where the join table is an entity in the model.)

How can I do **select** / **insert** / **update** or **delete** on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the `CategoryProduct` table is simply made up of two FKs one to `Product` and one to `Category`... the EF will by default not produce a `CategoryProduct` entity, instead to manipulate that table you will need to create / delete relationships using `Product.Categories` or `Category.Products` collections.

I.e. to add a row:

```
product.Categories.Add(category); // or category.Products.Add(product);
```

To remove a row:

```
product.Categories.Remove(category); // or visa versa
```

To query the table i.e. to get the rows in that table:

```
var pc = from c in ctx.Categories
         from p in c.Products
         select new {CategoryID = c.ID, ProductID = p.ID};
```

And update doesn't make sense, because the PK (which can't change) is all the columns, i.e. none of the row's columns can be update, so the row itself can't be updated (excluding deletes of course).

Hope this helps

Alex James

Comment: Thanks Alex. But how can I endit the columns of a product?
I get this error: 
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
The code is:
public static int Update(Product c)
        {
            using (SimvideoEntities ctx = new SimvideoEntities())
            {
                ctx.Attach(c);
                Common.SetModified(ctx, c);
               return ctx.SaveChanges(true);
            }
        }

Comment: Ok, I got the update & delete working but I have to get the record from the context first then save/delete it.

Comment: How would you make the "Get" LINQ query with method syntax?

Comment: Would this work (to retrieve the rows)? `context.Categories.Include(c => c.Products.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, at least two I can think of:

1. Have an entity for each object, this is nasty and it is, as usual hard to get the wiring correct.
2. Edit the model so that it models the many-to-many relationship as a many-to-many it will then do everything for you.

Option 2 is the better way but currently has the limitation that if you have other data associated with the CategoryProduct it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I did. Removed the middle class. So in the model it is a Many To Many and the CategoryProduct is gone.